# NGINX Error Code 502 / 503

Tags: nginx, php

I want to ask about the nginx web server, when accessing the web a lot, then the server becomes down and get an error code 502/504, I use varnish 4 in the web server with port 8000, the physical server has the following specifications:

8 CPU Cores
16GB RAM

For nginx configuration is as follows:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  8;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

pid        /run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 256k;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_max_temp_file_size 0;

    ......

}
```

While in php-fpm is as follows:

```
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 246
pm.start_servers = 32
pm.min_spare_servers = 32
pm.max_spare_servers = 64
```

Please help me feel confused, I followed some of the recommendations that I found from several sources, but still failed, thanks

Regards,
Janitra Panji

Comment: You didn't ask a question.

Comment: Okhay, my question is why the server always down and get the error code 502/504?

Answer (score 5):

The HTTP status codes you are asking about are all defined on the [related Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error)

- **502 Bad Gateway**
  The server was acting as a gateway or proxy and received an invalid response from the upstream server.
- **503 Service Unavailable**
  The server is currently unavailable (because it is overloaded or down for maintenance). Generally, this is a temporary state.
- **504 Gateway Timeout**
  The server was acting as a gateway or proxy and did not receive a timely response from the upstream server.

The all indicate that the service behind your Nginx reverse proxy is down for some reason or another. You should study the tuning of your backend server. The issue quite possibly there, and not with Nginx.